# Calculating chromatic polynomial for a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

This is the graph I'm trying to find its chromatic polynomial when $\lambda = 3$

[image]

This is my solution, first take look at this theorem:

**Theorem :** If $G = (V,E)$ is a graph and $G_1 , G_2$ are graphs such that $G = G_1\cup G_2$ and $G_1 \cap G_2 = K_n$ (where $K_n$ is a complete graph with $n$ nodes) then:

> $P(G,\lambda) = (P(G_1,\lambda).P(G_2,\lambda))/\lambda^n$

So to solve this problem I set

$G_1:$

[image]

$G_2:$

[image]

$G_1 \cap G_2 = K_2 :$

[image]

It is very easy to prove (it also has been proved in Grimaldi book) that

$P(G_1,\lambda) = \lambda^4 - 4\lambda^3 + 6\lambda^2 - 3\lambda = 18 $

So (when $\lambda = 3$ and $n = 2$)

$P(G,3) = 18 . P(G_2,3)/ 3^2 $

to find the chromatic polynomial of $G_2$ I use the above theorem again and set

$G_{21} : $

[image]

$G_{22} : $

[image]

So (again $\lambda = 3 $ and $n = 2$)

$P(G_2,\lambda) = P(G_{21},\lambda).P(G_{22},\lambda)/\lambda^n = 18 
\times 18 / 3^2 $

Now as a result

$P(G,3) = 18 . P(G_2,3)/ 3^2 = (18 * 18 * 18 / 3^4) = 72$

while `72` is not the correct answer because the options of the question are :

> $(1)81$     $(2)48$     $(3)162$     $(4)384$

**which part of my answer in not right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theorem is incorrect: the denominator should be the chromatic polynomial of $K_n$, which is $\lambda^{\underline{n}}=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)\ldots(\lambda-n+1)$, not $\lambda^n$. In particular, for $n=2$ it's $\lambda(\lambda-1)$.

Comment: @Drupalist: No, the theorem is stated correctly in Grimaldi. He uses the notation $\lambda^{(n)}$ for the [falling factorial](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) instead of the $\lambda^{\underline{n}}$ that I prefer, but it means the same thing: his $\lambda^{(2)}$ is $\lambda(\lambda-1)$, not $\lambda^2$.

Comment: @Drupalist: You're very welcome.